# Looping through columns and printing proportion or mean table based on condition with survey package

Tags: r, survey

I'm trying to loop through columns and print a proportion table if condition is met, or a mean table if condition is not met.

Data

```
library(survey)
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), weight=c(0,2,0.1), var1=c(2,3,4), var2=c(2,6,7))
design <- svydesign(id=~1, weights=~weight, data=dat)
cols <- c("var1", "var2")
type <- c("prop", "mean")
```

I tried:

```
for(i in seq_along(cols)){ 
ifelse(type[i]=="prop", 
print(prop.table(svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(cols[i]))), design))), 
            print(svymean(bquote(~.(as.name(cols[i]))), design))) }
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
'data' must be of a vector type, was 'language'
```

Comment: Capitalizing names of packages unnecessarily may confuse newbies. I would avoid that practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not very sure why the bquote is giving you so much problem, but if I use formula, it works ok:

```
for(i in seq_along(cols)){
FORMULA= as.formula(paste("~",cols[i]))
ifelse(type[i]=="prop", 
print(prop.table(svytable(FORMULA, design))), 
            print(svymean(FORMULA, design))) }

var1
         2          3          4 
0.00000000 0.95238095 0.04761905 
       mean     SE
var2 6.0476 0.0786
```